# Remove the last newline from file in Java

Tags: java, string, file

I want to delete the last newline present in my file using java. I mean, there is a newline at the very end of the file, which I want to remove.

I have tried many solutions provided online, but nothing works.

The below code removes all newlines from file

```
trimm.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
```

Sample text:

```
ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM"|dd1|1|"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM"|EST' ABC 20180821
ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM"|dd1|1|"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM"|EST' ABC 20180821
```

The above sample has newline at the end. I have referred the URLs below:

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-remove-a-newline-from-the-end-of-a-string.html

https://www.java-forums.org/new-java/22655-removing-last-blank-line-txt-file.html

I can't use `split()` after `\n` as many raws have same word

My code:

```
    String actual ="ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|\"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM\"|dd1|1|\"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM\"|EST' ABC 20180821\r\n" + 
            "ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|\"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM\"|dd1|1|\"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM\"|EST' ABC 20180821\r\n";
    try {
          File fout = new File("I:\\demo\\S2.txt");
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);
          BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
          String trimm= actual;
/*            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(trimm);
              int lastEnterPosition = trimm.lastIndexOf("\r\n");
              sb.replace(lastEnterPosition, lastEnterPosition + 1, "");
              trimm = sb.toString();*/
              trimm = trimm.replaceAll("[\n\r]+$", "");
              bw.write(trimm);
              bw.newLine();
              bw.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
              // File was not found
              e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              // Problem when writing to the file
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Any workaround will be helpful.

Comment: `String` has a [lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)) method that returns the index of the last instance of the specified argument. You could do `lastIndexOf("\n")`

Comment: @user1055395 - done .. put it into question

Comment: @Strikegently - can you please provide more info

Comment: @Strikegently - There are multiple enter in the file. It basically I want to remove the end. lastIndexOf("\n") will return the first enter value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replaceFirst` which use regex with this one `[\n\r]+$`, like so :

```
trimm = trimm.replaceFirst("[\n\r]+$", "");
```

### Full code

I tried this piece of code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String trimm = "ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|\"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM\"|dd1|1|\"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM\"|EST' ABC 20180821\n" +
            "ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|\"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM\"|dd1|1|\"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM\"|EST' ABC 20180821\r\n";

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------Before replace Start of the input---------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(trimm);
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------Before replace End of the input---------------------------------------------------");

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------After replace Start of the input---------------------------------------------------");
    trimm = trimm.replaceFirst("[\n\r]+$", "");
    System.out.println(trimm);
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------After replace End of the input---------------------------------------------------");

}
```

The output :

```
---------------------------------------------------Before replace Start of the input---------------------------------------------------
ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM"|dd1|1|"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM"|EST' ABC 20180821
ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM"|dd1|1|"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM"|EST' ABC 20180821

---------------------------------------------------Before replace End of the input---------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------After replace Start of the input---------------------------------------------------
ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM"|dd1|1|"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM"|EST' ABC 20180821
ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM"|dd1|1|"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM"|EST' ABC 20180821
---------------------------------------------------After replace End of the input---------------------------------------------------
```

---

Note that there are a break line before the replace and after the replace only the last break line is removed.

[**Ideone demo**](https://ideone.com/3kQbiU)

---

## More details

I tried this three solutions :

#### Code 1 (Your code)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String trimm = "ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|\"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM\"|dd1|1|\"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM\"|EST' ABC 20180821\n" +
            "ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|\"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM\"|dd1|1|\"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM\"|EST' ABC 20180821\r\n";

    try {
        File fout = new File("path");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
        trimm = trimm.replaceAll("[\n\r]+$", "");
        bw.write(trimm);
        //bw.newLine();//<-----------------------note this
        bw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // File was not found
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Problem when writing to the file
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

#### Code 2

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String trimm = "ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|\"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM\"|dd1|1|\"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM\"|EST' ABC 20180821\n" +
            "ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|\"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM\"|dd1|1|\"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM\"|EST' ABC 20180821\r\n";

    Path path = Paths.get("path");

    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path))
    {
        writer.write(trimm.replaceFirst("[\n\r]+$", ""));
    }
}
```

#### Code 3

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String trimm = "ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|\"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM\"|dd1|1|\"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM\"|EST' ABC 20180821\n" +
            "ABC 123|1|2 ABC '123|1|2|\"Jan 30 2018  2:34:13:000AM\"|dd1|1|\"Jan 30 2018  2:56:08:000AM\"|EST' ABC 20180821\r\n";

    try {
        Files.write(Paths.get("path"), trimm.replaceFirst("[\n\r]+$", "").getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and all the three codes gives me :

[image: result]

Comment: replaceAll will remove all enters .. I want to remove enter from last time only. BTW thanks for trying

Comment: @ShubhamJain If you want to remove the last one you can use `[\n\r]$` note the `$` which mean end of line check my edit

Comment: You might want to add a + or other repeat to the regex - if *both* `\r` and `\n` are present (as is the case in many files edited on Windows) this will remove only one of those.

Comment: @YCF_L - Not working, I have added my code in my answer. please try your side

Comment: @ShubhamJain I'm sure of my solution check my answer again and the ideone demo please

Comment: @ShubhamJain beside I see that you are using `bw.newLine();` why?

Comment: @Vasan it is `bw.newLine();`

Comment: nup I have not use sysoln .. but if you use my code and run it and open the file in notepad you can see a enter. Yes @YCF_L you output looks fine. still trying to identify the cause as I am still able to see enter in my notepad

Comment: @ShubhamJain note that in your code you are using `bw.write(trimm); bw.newLine();` note the `bw.newLine();` which mean after you write your string in the file you write also a new line

Comment: It feels do bad when a this small error like this has wasted your 3 hrs., seriously my bad and a stupid mistak :( ... Thanks buddy to clearfy same .. now working bw.newLine(); was the culprit

Comment: Its ok @ShubhamJain It happen to best of us you need a break time :)

Comment: exactly .. hahaha

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the string will always end with `\r\n`, given

```
String test = "your string that ends with a newline\r\n";
```

You can  use something like

```
String eol = "\r\n";
int eolLen = eol.length();
String tmp = test.substring(0, test.length()-eolLen);
```

Using a regex seems a bit overkill. You could optionally check to see that the string really ends with a newline and throw an exception of some kind or another if it's possible that you get bad input. Something like:

```
String check = test.substring(test.length() - eolLen);
if (!eol.equals(check)) {
    throw new Exception(String.format("Expected newline, found %s", check));
}
```